# wrap text inside div if too long

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a DIV that has a fixed width of 300px. My DIV is filled with dynamic texts that sometimes can become too long so part of the text is cut (because my div is only 300px wide). Is there a way that I can make the text inside my div to wrap when the length of the text exceeds 300px (I wanna make it wrap because my div does not have a fixed height).

Can this be done with only css or will I need some JS

Thank you

**NOTE**: I don't want to just increase the length of my DIV

Comment: It should wrap by default. Not enough info given. Can you post relevant html and css, please?

Comment: a `<div>` will wrap text and expand vertically by default.  There must be some style definition that it causing it to not behave properly.  Here is the standard behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/EbEZP/

Comment: This should happen by default. can you provide the css that is being applied to your div?
http://jsfiddle.net/NgLqs/

Answer (score 3):

Try using `word-wrap: break-word;` and ensure that there is no `overflow` set on the containing div.

Comment: there's no p inside the div, can I not apply that styling directly to the div?

Comment: Yes you can, however, you should really use a <p> as it is the correct tag for containing text.